# Encoder.htmlEncoder in JS

Tags: javascript, html-encode

On a website, I retrieve a string the user entered.

```
DataItem.getProperty('-----some name ----')
```

The problem is that some users put a `<script></script>` in there.

How can I escape/html-encode this string nicely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about;

```
function HTMLEncode(buff) {
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(buff));
    return e.innerHTML;
}


 In:  AAA <script>BBB</script> CCC &lt;DDD&gt;
 Out: AAA &lt;script&gt;BBB&lt;/script&gt; CCC &lt;DDD&gt;
```

Comment: wouldn't native method escape() be enought? Is there any native method that could achieve the same?

Comment: Well escape is for url encoding; it would convert < to something like %3Cb which - if you were to write it to the page (which is what i assume your doing) - you would see as "%3Cb". The example above would convert to &lt; which would be rendered correctly as the < character.

Comment: Here are some alternatives using .replace/jq; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript