# nodejs filtering inputs

Tags: php, node.js, filtering

In PHP to filter inputs data I use functions
htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string. Is there any functions like this in nodejs?

I need to check all inputs in my rounter functions to prevent hacker attacks like xss.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) is the perfect library for this, it has many functions for both validation and sanitation / filtering, for example:

```
entityDecode()                  //Decode HTML entities
entityEncode()
xss()                           //Remove common XSS attack vectors from text (default)
xss(true)                       //Remove common XSS attack vectors from images
```

or

```
contains(str)
notContains(str)
regex(pattern, modifiers)       //Usage: regex(/[a-z]/i) or regex('[a-z]','i')
notRegex(pattern, modifiers)
len(min, max)                   //max is optional
isUUID(version)                 //Version can be 3 or 4 or empty, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier
isDate()                        //Uses Date.parse() - regex is probably a better choice
isAfter(date)                   //Argument is optional and defaults to today
isBefore(date)                  //Argument is optional and defaults to today
isIn(options)                   //Accepts an array or string
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there php-like strip_tags function in that library?

Comment: I didn't see it, but here it is `function strip_tags(oldString) {
  return oldString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a NodeJS package for the [Google Caja HTML sanitizer](https://github.com/theSmaw/Caja-HTML-Sanitizer). Or you use the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript):

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
  return unsafe
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

For SQL it depends on what library you are using, but most of them will escape parameterized queries.