# Javascript encodeURIComponent doesn't encode single quotes

Tags: javascript

Try it out:

```
encodeURIComponent("'@#$%^&");
```

If you try this out you will see all the special characters are encoded except for the single quote. What function can I use to encode ALL the characters and use PHP to decode them?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the PHP part, please? How to you send them? What does currently not work?

Comment: The whole process is abit complicated to explain. I send the encoded value to the database using ajax and PHP (that's why the quote has to be encoded otherwise MySQL problems occur) then I retrieve the value using PHP and I decode it using rawurldecode()

Comment: Arghh, no! PHP **must** escape all SQL queries itself for security reasons. If the quotes needed to be escaped by JS you've done something wrong.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want them to be encoded. If you only want to escape single quotes, you could use `.replace(/'/g, "%27")`. However, good references are:

- [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75980/1048572)
- [Comparing escape(), encodeURI(), and encodeURIComponent()](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) at xkr.us
- [Javascript Madness: Query String Parsing](http://unixpapa.com/js/querystring.html) #Javascript Encode/Decode Functions

Comment: First I didn't want to use something like this but apparently PHP's rawurldecode supports the decoding of the quote from "%27". So, problem solved!
Cheers mate.

Comment: Regarding the question as to why you'd want to do this: If you want to use javascript to build html, e.g., `var html = "<a href='" + link + "'>foo</a>";` you will want to make sure the internal single quotes are properly escaped.

Comment: @speedplane But you don't use `encodeURI(Component)` for that. If you build HTML strings, you use `htmlAttributeEscape`!

Comment: @Bergi Is `htmlAttributeEscape` a standard function?

Comment: @speedplane No, I meant [any function that escapes HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1787322/1048572) attribute values

Comment: @Bergi Is that really the right way to do it? if `link="/?foo&bar"` that would result in an html link as `<a href='/?foo&amp;bar'>`. Wouldn't
 `encodeURIComponent(link).replace(/'/g, "%27")` be preferable?

Comment: @speedplane Yes it is. Entity-encoding the value is exactly the expected result. I don't see how `%2F%3Ffoo%26bar` would be preferable.

Comment: That's not quite the choice. If the URL is `/?foo='fiz'&bar`, then the choice is between: `/?foo=%27fiz%27&bar` and `/?foo=&#039;fiz&#039;&amp;bar`. Both are ugly but will probably work, the latter may be more pedanticly correct for HTML, but the former can be copied and pasted into a URL.

Comment: @speedplane Yes, the latter is the correct one. I guess whether you percent-encode or entity-encode the quotes doesn't matter, but you need to properly escape the *html special characters*. `encodeURIComponent` does not do that, it leads to `%2F%3Ffoo%3D'fiz'%26bar`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, escape);
}

fixedEncodeURIComponent("'@#$%^&");
```

Check reference: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent.html

Comment: Is there universal method to combine escape and encodeURIComponent?.. escape works with single quotes but fixedEncodeURIComponent with '#'..

Answer (score 4):

Just try `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` yourself...

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('@#$%^&*'));
```

Input: `@#$%^&*`.  Output: `%40%23%24%25%5E%26*`.  So, wait, what happened to `*`?  Why wasn't this converted?  TLDR: You actually want [`fixedEncodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`fixedEncodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).  Long-story...

`encodeURIComponent()` : ***Do not use.*** Use `fixedEncodeURIComponent()`, as defined and explained by the [**MDN `encodeURIComponent()` Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), emphasis mine...

> To be more stringent in adhering to ***RFC 3986 (which reserves !, ', (, ), and *)***, even though these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses, the following can be safely used:

> `function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) { return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) { return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); }); }`

While we're on the topic, also don't use `encodeURI()`.  MDN also has their own rewrite of it, as defined by the [**MDN `encodeURI()` Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).  To quote their explanation...

> If one wishes to follow the more recent RFC3986 for URLs, which makes square brackets reserved (for IPv6) and thus not encoded when forming something which could be part of a URL (such as a host), the following code snippet may help:

> `function fixedEncodeURI(str) { return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']'); }`

Answer (score 3):

**Recent answer (2021)**

Using JavaScript's [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```js
console.log(new URLSearchParams({ encoded: "'@#$%^&" }).toString())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `btoa()` and `atob()`, this encodes and decodes the given string including single quote.

Answer (score 1):

I found a neat trick that never misses any characters. I tell it to replace everything except for nothing. I do it like this (URL encoding):

```
function encode(w){return w.replace(/[^]/g,function(w){return '%'+w.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)})}
```

```js
function encode(w){return w.replace(/[^]/g,function(w){return '%'+w.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)})}

loader.value = encode(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<textarea id=loader rows=11 cols=55>www.WHAK.com</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Bergi wrote, you can just replace all the characters:

```
function encoePicture(pictureUrl)
{
 var map=
 {
          '&': '%26',
          '<': '%3c',
          '>': '%3e',
          '"': '%22',
          "'": '%27'
 };

 var encodedPic = encodeURI(pictureUrl);
 var result = encodedPic.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m];});
 return result;
}
```