# How to convert html special chars to ordinary HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, htmlspecialchars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)
>   [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript)

I need to convert with escaped htmlspecialchars to a valid HTML code, for example:

```
&lt;p&gt;Text here&lt;/p&gt;
```

should be displayed in the browser like

> Text here

What is the right way to do that?

Thanks in advance, Ivan.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame Side note: I totally agree with your name

Comment: stepped over this searching to savely replace &#123; into "TEXT" (not HTML!) with jquery... finaly confused by the other topic, i figured this out for me:

Comment: var htmlRegExConversion = new RegExp("&#(\\\\d+);");
while (htmlRegExConversion.test(anyText)) anyText = anyText.replace(htmlRegExConversion, function (e) { return String.fromCharCode(e.substring(2,e.length-1)*1); });

so this is not an answer for the question but maybe somebody as well hits this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery) and jQuery [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you were using jQuery. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the PHP.JS function to perform this action. Their examples solve exactly the question you are asking:

http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars_decode:427

Comment: the question never mentions php. what if we are not using php

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I didn't mention PHP, either. I said PHP.JS, which is a library which includes JavaScript implementations of many of PHP's built-in functions. It is purely a JavaScript implementation and is totally independent and unrelated to PHP.