# add characters that break html to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add this to a html text input.

```
var s = '>>>>>>>  """""""""""""';
```

How can I escape these characters so that it does not break the the HTML

```
var addMe = '<input type="text" value="' + s + '" />';
```

This is how it looks when its dynamically added with jquery

```
<input type="text" ??="" value=""/>
```

Comment: See [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.attr('value', ...)` to add arbitrary text to an element's value without needing to escape it.