# Unexpected identifier in Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, buttonclick

This seems to work 75% of the time and the modal function executes with the parameters available, but every few buttons in the table I'll get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Does this have to do with inproper closure? My google searches landed on that as a potential issue but I was unable to implement any of the solutions into my current method here.

```
html += '<thead><th>Question</th><th>Answer 1</th><th>Answer 2</th><th>Answer 3</th><th>Answer 4</th></thead>';

        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

            question = questions[i].question;
            questionTitle = question.q;
            answer1title = question.a1;
            answer2title = question.a2;

            html += '<tr><td class="question"><b>'
             + question.q
             + '</b></td><td class="answer1">'
             + question.a1
             + '</td><td class="answer2">'
             + question.a2
             + '</td><td class="answer3">'
             + question.a3
             + '</td><td class="answer4">'
             + question.a4
             + '</td><td class="edit">'
             + '<button onclick="openQuestionModal(\''+questionTitle+'\', \''+answer1title+'\', \''+answer2title+'\')" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" id="questionEdit" type="button">Edit</button>'
             + '</td></tr>';   

        }

        $('#questionsTable').append(html);
```

Comment: Where are you getting your `questions` from and how does it look?

Comment: Would/could any of `questionTitle`, `answer1title`, or `answer2title` have any single/double quotes in them?

Comment: I think some or more of the tags are not getting closed, hence the syntax error .

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - because, the contents of question might have literals which is causing this issue.

Comment: `questionTitle` or `answer1title` or `answer2title` contains a single quote `'`.

Comment: questions is a JSON parsed response from an API, I have verified that it is valid JSON and being parsed correctly.

Comment: @adeneo http://jsfiddle.net/ZYnfc/1/

Comment: I had done this in the past and never had any issues. Thanks for pointing out that its not the correct way to go about it. What do you recommend. I have changed the variables to be contained within the scope of the for loop and it hasnt helped.

Comment: One of the node's in the JSON array in question contains the word "I'm" but does not warn that its invalid JSON. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @user1909325 It's not invalid JSON, it's the fact that you're concatenating strings and not taking care of escaping quotes

Comment: Ok, what is the best practice here?

Comment: Just apply `htmlspecialchars` equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that any of `questionTitle`, `answer1title`, or `answer2title` may have a single quote in their values, which breaks the string concatenation you are attempting. You need to replace all occurrences of a single quote with an escaped single quote. So something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYnfc/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var par = "I'm the problem";
    var replacer = new RegExp("'", "g");
    var new_btn = $('<button onclick="clicker(\'' + par.replace(replacer, "\\'") + '\');">ASDF</button>');
    $("#main").append(new_btn);
});

function clicker(param) {
    alert(param);
}
```

You'll have to take my example and apply it to your actual code, but the main point is the use of the `replace` method and the `replacer` regex for each of your variables you're concatenating in the function call.

There are better ways to append HTML to an area, especially when it comes to a table. And I would suggest binding events with jQuery, not inline. That's a different topic and is unrelated to your problem, although it could've helped avoid it in the first place.

Comment: Can I just run this on the entire array to stamp out the problem before I even start looping?

I'd also like to see better examples on howto append HTML. I'm definitely open to learning better practices.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should escape the string before adding to onclick attribute:

```
+ '<button onclick="openQuestionModal(\''+ escape(questionTitle)+'\', \''+ escape(answer1title)+'\', \''+escape(answer2title)+'\')" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" id="questionEdit" type="button">Edit</button>'
```

And Use :

```
unescape('str_to_revert')// to get the data back inside your function.
```

Comment: I didnt downvote, but I did try it. It fixed the error but now all the data im passing is loaded with special characters (%20, etc)

Comment: This isn't the escaping you think it is. This `escape` function is for escaping URLs, and is really unnecessary for escaping a single quote, which is the main problem