# Is this a good string sanitizer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sanitize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript)

I couldn't find a good string sanitization function to be safely used inside HTML. I was wondering if this is a good approach:

```
String.prototype.sanitize = function() {
  return $('<div></div>').text(this).html();
}
```

Comment: Making a method of `String.prototype` aware of something like `jQuery` is a bad kind of coupling.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sanitizing against XSS, yes.  For sanitizing against SQL injections, no.

Comment: thanks! As my requirement is for front-end protection, this would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It's better (and still easy) to remove the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) requirement:

```
String.prototype.htmlspecialchars = function() {
  var span = document.createElement('span'),
  txt = document.createTextNode(this);

  span.appendChild(txt);

  return span.innerHTML;
}
```

The coupling with `document` still isn't so bad, because that's where it's going to be used anyway, but I prefer using successive `String.replace()` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4835406/1338292).

Comment: thats a nice refactoring. thanks Jack.