# Insert HTML codes in CKEditor textarea

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to know if there is a plugin in order to insert HTML codes in a CKEditor textarea?

I tried to install the PBCKCode plugin but it doens't work because the HTML is executed in my textarea.

Anthony

## EDIT1 ----- INSERTPRE Plugin -------

Query when I add the post :

```
    INSERT INTO `Posts` (`slug`,`title`,`thumbnail`,`content`,`tags`,`state`,`click`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`id`) VALUES ('dsq','dsq','http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-knCgLUMOkJc/TeMY2jkmACI/AAAAAAAAAV0/VByHmoMa2N8/s1600/first+blog+posting.jpg','<pre class="prettyprint">\r\n&lt;div&gt;toto&lt;/div&gt;</pre>\r\n\r\n<p>dqsdqs</p>\r\n','toto','0',0,'2013-04-30 12:15:46','2013-04-30 12:15:46',NULL);
```

The result in my textarea when I try to edit the post :

```
    <pre class="prettyprint">

    &nbsp;</pre>

    <div>toto</div>

    <p>dqsdqs</p>
```

As you can see the "div" have changed of place.

## EDIT2 ----- Escape HTML -------

Screenshot : http://grab.by/m8bs

As you can see it works in a P tag (just above the slug) but it doesn't work in my textarea. I think CKEditor encode my content but I don't know when and why... In my database everything is ok, I have the codes into the PRE tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "insert HTML codes in a CKEditor textarea"? And note that CKEditor replaces textarea with an iframe containing editable element. Textarea is only a source of data.

Comment: I wanna add some codes like "PHP Code", "Javascript Code", "HTML Code", ect... In order to explain something in web development.

Comment: **Update**: That's because you're not encoding HTML before you pass it to textarea. Use `htmlspecialchars` (or other similar function if you're not using PHP) to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Check these two plugins:

- http://ckeditor.com/addon/insertpre
- http://ckeditor.com/addon/syntaxhighlight

We use the first one on http://ckeditor.com/forum and it works very well.

**Update:** That's because you're not encoding HTML before you pass it to textarea. Use htmlspecialchars (or other similar function if you're not using PHP) to do that.

**Update2:** You are doing something wrong, but I don't know on what stage. The output data (`editor.getData()`) from the editor with one `<pre>` element is:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">&lt;div&gt;</pre>
```

See that `<pre>` is not encoded, but `<div>` inside it is. Your examples show me that you "flattened" that structure - you have encoded both things equally when it should be:

```
&lt;pre class=&quot;prettyprint&quot;&gt;&amp;lt;div&amp;gt;&lt;/pre&gt;
```

Note: `&amp;lt;` is an encoded `&lt;`.

Comment: Update in my post. I got an issue with INSERTPRE.

Comment: I use NodeJS and ExpressJS. So it's in Javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript

Comment: I tried to use your function but I got the same thing. The most impressive is that I can show the HTML content in a P tag. See above #EDIT2.

Comment: @Reinmar: I'm trying "insertpre" with version 4.3 of the editor, but it seems to do nothing, presumably because its last known compatible version was 4.1. Any suggestions on alternatives to edit a `<pre>` without having to write a widget-based editor from scratch? I am guessing "syntaxhighlight" doesn't actually offer an editor, and at the time of writing, their online demo is broken. Thanks for any suggestions you might be able to offer!

Comment: CKEditor 4.4 will introduce official [code snippet](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11480) plugin. It's pretty ready now, but 4.4 will be released within 2 months. I don't know anyting about [insertpre](http://ckeditor.com/addon/insertpre)'s compatibility with 4.3, although I see that it works on http://ckeditor.com/forums. Try contacting its author.

Comment: Thanks @Reinmar - didn't get a notification of your comment. I'll make a note to get in touch with the author, good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use source menu in ck editor header to add your html

Use this tutorial
[demo link](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

Comment: I wanna add some codes in my article, I mean, I don't want that the HTML will be executate in my article.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Try This

for added Post

```
addslashes($_POST['post_from_textarea']);
```

to Edit

```
stripslashes($yourvairablegetRowsQuery)
```

Comment: addslashes()? What's next? enhancesvolume(), reducesageing(), coverswrinkles()?

Comment: @nimasmi addslashes() is php's way of escaping certain characters.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. I was facetiously parsing it as 'adds lashes', as in cosmetics advertisements.