# HTML Codes in my CKEditor Textarea Issue

Tags: ckeditor

I get an issue when I try to add some HTML codes in my CKEditor textarea, my HTML is executed in the textarea. I mean, all my HTML codes have changed of place in my Textarea, so how can I fix it?

Before adding a post on my website, I put this in my textarea :

```
<pre><div>toto</div></pre>
```

The post in my database (everything is ok):

```
<pre><div>toto</div></pre>
```

When I try to edit the post, the content is reformated in my CKEditor textarea :

```
<pre>&nbsp;</pre><div>toto</div>
```

So I think the main issue is CKEditor, maybe he reformat or encode all my HTML code, I don't know what's going on...

**EDIT 1:**

Config file of CKEditor

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' },
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode'] }, // shows the source button
        { name: 'pbckcode' }
    ];

    config.extraPlugins = 'pbckcode';

    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
};
```

My add post view:

```
extends admin_layout
block content
    div.container
        h1 Wellcome to administration pannel
        div.space20
        div.block.first
            h2 Add post
            div.wrap
                form(action="/posts/add", method="post").admin
                        textarea(class="ckeditor", id="ckeditorFilter", placeholder="Content...", name="content", rows="15")
                        br
                    input(type="submit", value="Save")
    script(src="/admin/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")
    script
        CKEDITOR.replace('content',{
            toolbar: 'Basic',
            uiColor: '#0091BD'
        });
```

My edit post view :

```
extends admin_layout
block content
    div.container
        h1 Wellcome to administration pannel
        div.space20
        div.block.first
            h2 Edit post
            div.wrap
                - each p in post
                    p= p.content
                    form(action="/posts/add", method="post").admin
                            textarea(class="ckeditor", id="ckeditorFilter", placeholder="Your content...", name="content", rows="15", required)!= p.content
                            br
                        input(type="submit", value="Edit")
    script(src="/admin/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")
    script
        CKEDITOR.replace('content',{
            toolbar: 'Basic',
            uiColor: '#0091BD'
        });
```

Comment: I think you are adding an extra pre, from what I can tell. Try to remove the original pre from the page and try it. Although I could be wrong as I am not exactly sure what the page setup is. By that I mean before the post should not have a pre I believe. Unless the editor is placed after the call to your DB?

Comment: I use a plugin in order to add some HTML codes. (plugin : http://ckeditor.com/addon/pbckcode). But for example, when I try to show the post into a P tag, it works, I see the right post "<pre><div>toto</div></pre>"...

Comment: hmmmm I see well then, the only thing I can thing of is maybe the pluggin can only be inserted into certain blocks(DOM elements). My suggestion is to ask the developers of the plugin. Other than that goodluck sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: Yea but I tried to contact the developer of the plugin and I got no responses... I tried two differents plugins and I got the same thing, the PRE content change of place... I don't think that the issue is due to the plugin...

Comment: hmmm could you post a little more code specifically dealing with the ckeditor configuration steps and how exactly you are getting your data.

Comment: I added some more codes. But I don't think that can help you, my view are using JADE. And I use ExpressJS for the back-end.

Comment: OK I took a look at some of the CKeditor docs and disscusions on pre. It seems like there may be a bug in the CKeditor backend that is messing with the pre elements on your page. Take a look at this I am just curious if this is something like what you are experiencing: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/404  Also take a look at this plugin to do with pre's with, although I am not sure how the plugin you are currently using deals with them. http://ckeditor.com/addon/insertpre

Comment: Ok so it's maybe the issue. But in your ticket I don't understand what I have to do in order to fix it. Do you know what I have to do?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like a running issue with the CKeditor back-end you could try using the nightly build to see if it is fixed there. I will continue looking for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your help. I hope you will find the issue. For my part, I try the nightly build but I'm not sure I will find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've already answered your question here: [Insert HTML codes in CKEditor textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292733/insert-html-codes-in-ckeditor-textarea)

You're encoding content incorrectly when writing it to the textarea.

Comment: Ok but I already tried to use your function in order to encode my content but it doesn't work, what am I suppose to do?