# Embed < and > as text in a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a code sample where I want "<" and ">" to be interpreted as standard text. If I do the following

```
<pre>
    Some content that contains <and>
</pre>
```

It will not be interpreted properly unless I html encode my "<"/ ">" characters. 
Is there simple way around this?

Test Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/Az3hZ/

Comment: Don't know if you mean something like the top answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript ?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding?

Comment: Thanks @Andi I'll use that. I'll have to load files via ajax calls instead of a simple copy paste but I guess its better than way anyways since code samples will stay relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your HTML document is XML, `<and>` is a new tag.

See [XML predefined entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-predefined-ent).

You have no choice but to encode it.

Comment: Thanks for explicitly mentioning "no choice".

Comment: -1 - HTML != XML. For example `<br>` is valid HTML, but not valid XML. HTML _is_ however SGML (though HTML 5 has divorced itself from that, IIRC)

Answer (score 4):

You can encode the brackets:

- `>` = `&gt;`
- `<` = `&lt;`

So:

```
<pre>
    Some content that contains &lt;and&gt;
</pre>
```

Comment: @0xBAADF00D - Technically, yes. But I like the symmetry and explicitness here.