# Escaping error message in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, escaping, xss

I have this code in my program:

```
res.send('<html><script>window.opener.alert("' + message + '");window.close();</script></html>');
```

Now... `message` is something I cannot really predict, although it does come back from an established API and it SHOULD be ok. However, "should" is just not good enough.
I realise that I have to escape any `"` (or it will break the string). However...

- Do I need to escape anything else?
- Is there a ready-to-to function for this?

Comment: you can use underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/#escape it has many utility functions

Comment: Use the function in this answer to escape: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript

Comment: what is the server side technology used?

Comment: Apologies, it's nodejs on the server side. Sorry, I thought res.send would make it obvious...!

Comment: @MrCode: you should post this as an answer, because its the correct anser!

Comment: @hereandnow78 yeah I was going to post as answer but thought it would be a duplicate. Actually looking at it again you would need some other solution because `alert()` doesn't decode HTML entities, so you would see literally `&amp;` and `&quot;` etc. Personally I would put the message in the body of the new window instead of an alert.

Answer (score -1):

Use the v8 [btoa and atob shim](http://bbenvie.com/articles/2012-06-06/ES6-Private-Names-Shim) to encode and decode the message:

```
res.send('<html><script>window.opener.alert("' + btoa(message) + '");window.close();</script></html>');
```

Or JSON.stringify:

```
res.send('<html><script>window.opener.alert("' + JSON.stringify(message) + '");window.close();</script></html>');
```

Comment: Not sure if you missed something in your answer... but doing a `btoa` will scramble the message!

Comment: So if you unscramble it using atob(btoa(message)), does it return different text than the original?

Comment: It doesn't, no, but what's the point to scramble/unscramble if the result is the same?

Comment: That's not the point. The point is to escape and unescape a message. Is it useful for that? Only you know the answer.

Comment: I need to show "A" without worrying about special characters. Scramble "A", and then unscramble, and then show it (without escaping special characters) is pointless, since the scramble -> unscrable process does not bring you _any_ benefits.

Comment: Of course not, it's a two step process. You scramble it in one function, pass the scrambled text to another function, then unscamble it before printing to the screen.

Comment: Replace window.opener.alert with a function call. That function takes the scrambled text as a parameter. Inside that function, it unscrambles the text and prints it via `window.opener.alert`.

Comment: Any special characters will _still_ be present in `window.opener.alert`! The scramble/unscramble process is pointless, the problem is with what's passed to `window.opener.alert`!

Comment: That is not clear from your question. If you need to avoid breaking the string, then simply use window.opener.alert(message).