# append div in jquery with quotes in field

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i have a this code but i have a problem with quotes in javascript:

```
var content = 'peter says: 'hello'';
```

and

```
var append = '<div class="'+content+'>';
```

how proteted quotoes ?? attribtties class only show: `peter says:` 
thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: replace quotes in text that you're inserting into attributes with their entity equivalents. `&#39;` for `'` and `&quot;` for `"`

Comment: Keep in mind that javaScript allows different types of quotes   ' ' and " " take a read over this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript it talks about it some.  Also http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp is quite informative.

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = "peter says: 'hello'";
```

Escape the quotes.

This would work as well (put a back slash in front of the quote you want to display):

```
var content = 'peter says: \'hello\'';
```

Comment: thanks but the problem in this case with text with quotes doubles.

Comment: fin soluction in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by escaping it using **`\"`**

```
var content = 'peter says: \"hello\"';
```

However this should work

```
var content = 'peter says: "hello"';
```

To support, I have added [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/znCQZ/)

> There is no need to escape double quotes within single quotes or vice versa.  However escaping is a standard approach.

Here I got a [**reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/242833/1671639) too

Comment: @user2799505 I have added few details and reference.  Though you already got your answer, I would like you to take a look at the reference for a good understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Is that fiddle answers your question

```
<div id="test">

</div>


$(function()
  {
      var content = "petersays: 'hello'";
      var classToAppend = "class=\""+content+"\"";
      var append = "<div +classToAppend+">test</div>";
     $("#test").append(append);      
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29fLy/2/