# Output script tags without jQuery, avoiding execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

I have JS calling remote server through AJAX. The response contains something similar to this

```
<script>alert(document.getElementById('some_generated_id').innerHTML; ... </script>
```

User copies the response and uses for own purposes. Now I need to make sure that not a single browser runs the code when I do this:

```
var response = '<scrip.....';
document.getElementById('output_box').innerHTML = response;
```

Same should apply to any `HTML` tags. I know that `.text()` from jQuery will do exactly what I need:

```
var response = '<scrip.....';
$('#output_box').text(response);
```

I am looking for any solutions, including, but not limited to: escaping special characters, however displaying them correctly; adding zero-width space to tags (has to be efficient); outputting in parts. Has to be pure JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a server-side language there is probably a method to escape special characters.

In PHP you could use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), it will convert certain characters that have significance in HTML to HTML entities (i.e. & to &).
They will still display correctly and you'll be able to copy and paste the text, but the javascript shouldn't run.

If you need a pure javascript solution for this, someone has answered that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4835406/15000

Comment: Thanks. I am using server-side, however this has to be done at client. Solution is exactly what I was looking for but could not find.