# Printing double quote in textbox in javascript

Tags: jquery

I have double quotes as well as single quotes in a TD element. On click of that TD I'm passing value inside that TD to the function and create input element.
For the single quotes it's working fine, but in case of double quotes it's removing string after the double quotes.

[Have a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F68bm/1/), I tried escape and unescape but that also not working, I also tried replace function.

```
$(".table td").click(function(){
    var input = createInput($(this).html());
    $(this).html(input);
});

createInput = function(str){
    str = typeof str !== 'undefined' ? str : "";
    input = '<input value="'+str+'">';
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Ok. You kinda have to ask a question before we can help

Comment: What do you have now, can you show a small demo of the problem, and some expected results?

Comment: I am sorry i was facing problem posting question, so i tried with some sample text and it worked, Now i have edited the question, M also trying to add jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/F68bm/1/

Comment: You forgot to add the fiddle :)

Comment: Post Your Solution as an answer!! It's cool to have the solution by yourself!

Comment: @Martijn : i am not able to add the jsfiddle link as a link, so i have added it as string.

Comment: @www.amitpatil.me , look at answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/F68bm/6/

```
$(".table td").click(function(){
    var input = createInput($(this).html());
    $(this).html(input);
});

createInput = function(str){
    //alert(str);
    str = typeof str !== 'undefined' ? str : "";
    input = '<input value='+str+'>';
    return input;
}
```

What was problem was your Quoting , so proper is

```
input = '<input value='+str+'>'
```

Consider it as 3 parts

**1)** `< input value=` ,Here it is static part ,evaluated as it is in HTML

**2)** `+str+`  Here this is dynamic part added after processing .

**3)** `>` ,This is also static part ,put as it is in HTML ,

Its simple :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".table td").click(function() {
    var input = createInput($(this).html());
    $(this).html(input);
});

createInput = function(st){
    st = typeof st !== 'undefined' ? st : "";
    input = $('<input type="text">').val(st);
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Love this approach as well

Answer (score 0):

You can escape quotes to stop them from ending your string prematurely.

```
/* javascript */

var str = "My string is \"awesome\".";

console.log(str);        //prints: My string is "awesome".
```

Answer (score 0):

For php language this **htmlspecialchars** function useful to display double/single quotes ( " / ' ) in textbox

PHP Example :

```
<!-- For PHP -->
<input type="text" value="<?=htmlspecialchars('YOUR DOUBLE " /SINGLE ' QUOTES STRING')?>">
```

For JS you can refer this link [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript)