# Javascript / jQuery: How to convert string to HTML character code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I have a string that contains text including special characters like apostrophes, quotes, ampersand etc. that I would like to convert to HTML character codes, e.g. to show `&#39` instead of an apostrophe etc. (as per the following list: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html.

I do not necessarily need to convert letters and spaces as long as the above and some other basic characters are encoded correctly.

For a temporary workaround I use simple replaces like `str = str.replace("'", "&#39")` but would like to avoid this as it only covers certain characters.

I was thinking of `encodeURI` or `encodeURIcomponent` but would like to know what is the best and easiest way to achieve this without encoding more than necessary.

Can someone tell what is the best way here if the idea is to avoid any issues with other JS where this is inserted dynamically, esp. thinking of single quotes, double quotes and any other character that could cause issues here (referring to JavaScript / jQuery and English language only) ?

Comment: I was going to ask this question about a month ago... then forgot.

Comment: Javascript doesn't really have an entity encoder built in, URI encoding is something completely different. The best option is probably replacement, and that makes this a duplicate.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript , it seems beeing a similar article

Answer (score 1):

```
function encodeEntities(value) {
    return $('<div />').text(value).html();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! Will this cover all the above examples ?