# Pass html variable from Ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use this code to pass via POST a variable containing HTML

```
var data = {
    message: $('#mydiv').html()
};
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    url: '/myurl?action=send_email',
    success: function( response ) { }
});
```

In PHP, I retrieve the data and I send an Email using the data content

```
$message = "Hello<br>" . $_POST['message'] . "<br>Bye Bye";
$mail = mail($email, $subject, nl2br($message), $headers);
```

The HTML within the email that I receive is badly formatted:

```
<img width="\&quot;70\&quot;" height="\&quot;87\&quot;" alt="\&quot;D_6928_antiqueoak_vapor\&quot;">
```

Can someone tell me why and if there is a solution? Thank you a lot

Comment: Why on earth are you sending HTML?

Comment: Uh... Why not? Do you receive a lot of plain-text e-mails? With no formatting, no line breaks and all?

Comment: @Ruben what are your mail headers? Did you activate UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: No I mean why are you sending HTML from the browser to your server. Its going to be really difficult to validate or sanitize, just use `$.data()` or `$.attr('whatever')` and send plain data which you then construct HTML with.

Comment: @papirtiger you can send html esay enough, why would you bother reconstructing the html on the server side if you can just grab it from the client side already laid out and ready to go. Not to mention it would make it easier to abstract your php code

Comment: Because of [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Find the old question link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this method using `encodeURIComponent()`

```
var data = 'message='+$('#mydiv').html();
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: encodeVars(data),
    url: '/myurl?action=send_email',
    success: function( response ) { }
});


function encodeVars(vars){
    return vars.map(function (cell) {
        var res = cell.split('=');
        return res[0] + '=' + encodeURIComponent(res[1]);
    }) ;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always set content-type when sending HTML email

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I don't think this could be related to the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved in that way. Javascript

```
var data = {
    message: $('#mydiv').html()
};
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: data.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
            .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
            .replace(/'/g, "&#039;"),
    url: '/myurl?action=send_email',
    success: function( response ) { }
});
```

PHP

```
$message = preg_replace('/&amp;/', '&', $_POST['message']);
$message = preg_replace('/&quot;/', '"', $message);
$message = preg_replace('/&#039;/', "'", $message);
$message = "Hello<br>" . $message . "<br>Bye Bye";
$mail = mail($email, $subject, nl2br($message), $headers);
```