# How can I escape double quotes from a text input in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In a variable, string data is coming from text input like following.

```
var noteStr="<?php echo $_REQUEST["noteStr"];?>";
```

If user given any double quotes in text input then javascript give an error as expected. I am not finding a way to use javascript str.replace() in this scenario because before using that on string variable javascript engine generate errors.

How can i solve this problem using javascript?
Advance thanks for help.

Comment: using backslashes like \" or you can use '

Comment: possible duplicate of [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP function [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

```
var noteStr="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["noteStr"]); ?>";
```

And here's JavaScript equivalent:

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };

  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
```

Source: [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript)

Comment: I need to know how this can  be handle using javascript

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome inbuild function in Javascript. escape() funtion.

```
<script>

document.write(escape("Hello friends? Here is the solution!"));

</script>
```

Will become-

```
Hello%20friends%3F%20Here%20is%20the%20solution%21
```

Check out- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_escape for reference

This can also be achieved by using Prototype in Javascript. A simple example-

```
var str = '<div class="article">This is an article</div>';
document.write( str.escapeHTML() );
```

Will become-

> ```
> &lt;div class="article"&gt;This is an article&lt;/div&gt;
> ```

Source : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=prototype_83

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: escape function is deprecated in javascript.