# How to allow showing caharcaters like single quote, double quotes, new line charcters in html text area in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I am facing

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal*

error while trying to set a value in text area.

Here, The text value is dynamic and receiving from the backend and that can contain any characters.

After my first investigation, i could find that the error is due some special characters in the text like singlequote, double quotes and new line character.

how can I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Okay, so following your comments, changing it at the php level is not an option.

There is a great answer offered on a similar question here at stackoverflow;

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
  return text
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

Pass your variable into this function before applying it to the text area. Pseudo code;

```
var yourTextVariable = "random/stuff&in\Here";
var formattedVariable = escapeHtml(yourTextVariable);
$('textarea').html($formattedVariable);
```

Originally answerd by Kip at [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript)

Comment: sorry Lewis.. Here I am not using php.  Value is setting into the text are by jquery

Comment: Fair enough, took a leap! :) So how are you retrieving the value?

Comment: retrieving the value from DB and setting in an object, I have even tried repalcing few special characters while setting  into this object.. like \n to <br\> " to \\\"... But what change needs to be doen in javascript level to diaply the value    `function setValue(notes){

 $('#notesId').html(notes);
 }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the time. `Let me ask another concern here. How can i pass a text with ',",newline as an argument in the function invoked in the **OnClick event**.`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape all HTML special characters:

- `&quot;` for a quote (")
- `&gt;` for greater than (>)
- ...

Here is the full list: [HTML: Special Characters](https://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html)