# Stop <script> being entered through x-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

We use [x-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) for fast edit rows. We have noticed a small bug. When a `<script>` tag is entered in to the editable input it will be executed.

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

```js
$('.edit').editable({
    params: function(params) {
        var data = {};
        data['id']          = params.pk;
        data[params.name]   = params.value;
        return data;
    },
    success: function(response, newValue){
        $(".test").html(newValue); 
        //if newValue will be <script>alert('hello')</scipt>
        // then we see alert message with 'hello'
    }
});
```

For example, if `newValue` had a string value of `<script>alert('hello')</script>`, then we see an `alert` message appear with 'hello'.

How can we stop this behaviour?

Comment: Use `text()` instead of `html()`

Comment: Hmm, but how pass newValue in function(response, newValue) ???   Magic?

Comment: @MaximColesnic not sure if you're talking to me, but it's just an anonymous function which is passed the specified parameters, the same as any other anonymous function when used as an event handler.

Comment: Open editable plugin and find succes function. I think then "success" function have one param "response".

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good idea, but unfortunately it does not fit. we need to use that html(it simple code, in success other function output notify html with this value)

Comment: @MaximColesnic no it has two, check the link to the docs in the question. OPs code is fine in that regard

Comment: @user4731956 in that case you would need to specifically find instances of `<script` in the `newValue` and either remove them, or prevent the user from submitting.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in php exist function [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php). it is posible in javascript?

Comment: It is, but that's what `text()` does (in effect) and you said that would not fit you needs.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan we can not use function text() becouse in success exist function which output this and other code with html(). but now idea use analog htmlspecialchars() before html().

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan for example can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4835406/5398808) and then make function with html()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace in the input the string "script" with "code"... that way it will be output as "text". something like this maybe...

```
$('.edit').editable({
params: function(params) {
    var data = {};
    data['id']          = params.pk;
    data[params.name]   = params.value;
    return data;
},
success: function(response, newValue){
    //gi: Perform a global, case-insensitive replacement:
    newValue = newValue.replace(/script/gi, "code");
    $(".test").html(newValue); 
    //if newValue will be <script>alert('hello')</scipt>
    // then we see alert message with 'hello'
}
});
```

[JavaScript String replace() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)