# How to allow user to input escaped chars in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

A simple one here.

I have an HTML `<textarea>` in which I want to allow the user to enter escape sequence. I.e.:

```
Hello\nworld\x21
```

And I want my script to "interpret" the `\n` and the `\x21` to get:

```
Hello
world!
```

Thanks

EDIT:
The purpose of this is to allow the user to enter thermal printer's code in an html page. The printer needs special chars. I want to take that string, "interpret" the special codes and send it to the printer. Currently, the printer prints the string as-is.

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and what issues did you have in your attempt?

Comment: Looks alot like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript/4835406#4835406

You need to make a converter and split the string i guess.

Comment: also, what is your expected output for backslashes used for non-escapes? for example what should ``\`` produce, or ``\ ``?

Comment: I added an edit to explain my needs

Comment: @zzzzBov I do not need output. I send the string to a thermal printer

Comment: @vIceBerg, I don't really care what you *do* with the output. I'm asking what your expectations are, because it seems as though you haven't really defined the behavior yet. For some input string `in` you expect some output string of `out`, to properly answer the question requires that the input and output expectations are well defined. As it stands your question reads more like a work order. You haven't shown any attempt at solving it yourself, so I'm going to vote to close this as too broad, although "unclear" would also be appropriate.

Comment: @zzzzBov I just don't understand how can I be more precise. My user enters a string in which it has escaped sequence in it and I want those escape sequence to be change by it's real char representation. So it I have a string with litteral \x21 in it, I want it to be converted to !

Comment: @vIceBerg, I already asked what ``\`` and ``\ `` would produce. What about `\u0021`? How about `\u{0000000000000021}`? Are you expecting standard JavaScript string escapes to work? Would `\0` produce a null character and break anything? My point is that a naive question begets a naive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The only way I can think of that doesn't use a *long* replace line is with the `eval()` function. You could, for example, use the following:</strike>

```
function useEscapes(s) {
    return eval('("' + s.replace(/([^\\]|^)(?=(\\\\)*["\n])/g, '$1\\').replace(/\n/g, 'n') + '")');
}
```

The `replace` is to make sure it's safe to pass into the `eval()` function.

EDIT 9/28/2016:

There's a better way that isn't a security risk. Because a string literal is valid JSON, you can wrap it in quotes and use `JSON.parse`. You can also possibly escape quotes in it so that users don't get inexplicable syntax errors. If an attacker tries to put code outside the string, it will just throw a syntax error.

```
function useEscapes(s) {
    return JSON.parse('"' + s
        .replace(/((^|[^\\])(\\\\)*)"/g, '$1\\\\"') // optional - prevents syntax errors
        + '"');
}
```

Comment: The only "bug" is if there's a carriage return in the user's input string, the function returns a Unexpected token ILLEGAL error.

Comment: Good luck with `'"'` as input, and moreso for having opened your app to a user being able to unknowingly execute arbitrary JavaScript.

Comment: Say it's an oversight. Second replace optional.