# Displaying command as text

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
var element = '<button>'+text+'</button>';
$('#output').append(element+"\n");
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
```

I want it so the element (button) display in textarea as text not element. I want it to display:

```
'<button>Hi</button>'
```

if text = "Hi"
Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` instead of `.append()`:

```
$('#output').val(element+"\n");
```

Comment: it has to be append.

Comment: @killereks Why does it have to be append? If you need to build on the input just use `$('#output').val( $('#output').val() + element + "\n");`

Comment: because i have many other lines in there ? I need it to be append so it gets added.

Comment: When i use val other lines do not get appended ;/

Comment: @killereks That's because you are overwriting the value with a new one so you need to get the existing value before adding new content to it. J08691 shows you how to do that in the comment above

Comment: @j08691Maybe update your answer to show the same as your fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, use `val()` but you want to get the existing value before overwriting it. The reason for this answer being posted is due to the other one not being updated.

> Working Demo

```js
$("#Example").on( "click", function() {
  //Add new input before existing content
$('#output').val($('#input').val()+"\n"+$('#output').val());
  //Add new input after existing content
//$('#output').val( $('#output').val() +$('#input').val()+ "\n");  
 $('#input').val('');
  $('#input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input"/><button id="Example">Add</button><br/>
<textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
```

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1kqpxzzz/1/)

To preset the text into a button you can wrap the button tags around the input value.

Example: `"<button>"+$('#input').val()+"</button>"` [**JS Fiddle Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/1kqpxzzz/2/)

> Demo Two

```js
$("#Example").on( "click", function() {
//New input before existing content
 $('#output').val("<button>"+$('#input').val()+"</button>\n"+$('#output').val());
 //New input after existing content
 //$('#output').val( $('#output').val() +"<button>"+$('#input').val()+ "</button>\n");
  $('#input').val('');
  $('#input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input"/><button id="Example">Add</button><br/>
<textarea id="output" readonly></textarea>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this help. Happy coding!