# How to print circled plus in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print the circled plus in JavaScript to an HTML page.

Here is how the [circled plus](http://graphemica.com/%E2%8A%95) looks like.

I saw this solution but I can not figure out how to apply it for this symbol: [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript/4835406#4835406)

Comment: How about `"\u2295"` or simply `"⊕"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo:

```js
document.body.textContent = '\u2295';
```

```css
body { font-size: 50px }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `&oplus;`:

```js
document.getElementById('js').innerHTML = '&oplus;'
```

```html
<div>&oplus;</div>  <!-- ⊕ -->
<div id='js'></div> <!-- ⊕ -->
```