# Escaping string using JavaScript before populating form input

Tags: javascript, escaping, quotes

I have this code where I grab an attribute value and load it into a form, the headline line can look something like:

**Welcome to America's best valued whatever**

But when using this escape function, the string is cut off at the apostrophe,

```
var headline = escape($(this).attr("data-headline"));

//populate the textbox
$(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="headline"]').val(headline);
```

I've also tried using the solutions here: [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript) with no luck.

How can I populate my input and keep apostrophe's/quotes?

Comment: You can just use `$('input[name="headline"]', e.currentTarget)` to select vs select and find. Why do you need to escape it in the javascript? Just setting the value shouldnt cause any issues.

Comment: What's the point of calling `escape` here? a) [it does not do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) what you think it does b) there's no need to escape a string that goes into `.val()`!

Comment: `escape` seems to be deprecated and mostly used for `URIs` rather than for escaping apostrophes

Comment: `escape` is long time deprecated and should not be used for what you try to achieve. I'm sure jQuery has another function which you can use.

Comment: Why is my string being cut off at the apostrophe when populated into .val()? @Bergi

Comment: @handlethisman Have you tried `console.log($(this).attr("data-headline"))` to check what your string actually is?

Comment: The problem is probably when you was setting the attribute at the first place. Take a look at the element, it's probably looks like this: `<tag data-headline='Welcome to America's best valued whatever ></tag>` which then the value of the attribute will be `Welcome to America` and the rest will be regarded as attributes themselves `<tag s best valued whatever>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
$(this).find('input[name="headline"]').val(this.dataset.headline);
```

No need for any escaping.

However, notice that `escape` does not cut off apostrophes, it replaces them with `%27`. If your current code does not work with apostrophes in the headline, make sure that the markup containing the `data-headline` attribute is properly escaped by whatever tool is creating it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you were right about escaping the attribute properly.  

Using PHP, this worked for me:

<button class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal_create_article' data-headline='".htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES)."'>+</button>

Answer (score -2):

```
var headline = $(this).attr("data-headline").replace(/'/g, '%27');
//populate the textbox
$(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="headline"]').val(unescape(headline));
```

If browser compatibility is important, dataset is only available IE11+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Browser_compatibility

Comment: You are aware that `unescape()`is deprecated, right? New versions of browsers might drop it's compatibility completely.