# Decode html entities with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, decode

How can i decode html entities with jquery like with php function htmlspecialchars_decode? I have this code:

```
                if (jQuery.trim(jQuery("#push_alert").val()) != "") {
                alert = jQuery("#push_alert").val();
            }
```

And whenever the text has `&` in it, it outputs `%amp;` Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript

Comment: That's the opposite of what i want

Answer (score 0):

As far i know jQuery itself will give you whatever you entered as a string.

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"> a & b</textarea>
        $('#mytextarea').keyup(function() {
             alert($(this).val())
         });
```

You can provide exact html and jQuery code to investigate further.
Here is jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/0ynm4zf1/