# recursive echo inside laravel collective form blade

Tags: laravel, translation, laravel-blade, laravel-form

is it correct that I cannot do things like:

```
   {{ Form::label('search',{!!__('messages.rep_findUsr')!!} )}}
```

do I need to store it before in a var and then pass it as argument?

or there is a faster way?
thanks

Comment: if in `./project/resources/lang/**/messages.php` you have it in the returning array it should show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply set the fourth parameter to false to disable html escaped:

```
{{ Form::label('search',__('messages.rep_findUsr'), [], false) }}
```

[**Form::label declaration**](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.6/src/FormBuilder.php#L240)

```
public function label($name, $value = null, $options = [], $escape_html = true);
```

Comment: ok so my wrong step was about put double brackets inside another double... escaping is the next thing I guess... is it possible to insert those kinds of "special echo" even inside the "script/jQuery part" of the blade template? thanks

Comment: `{{ }}` basically using `htmlspecialchars` php function to escape special characters, you can find the equivalent js function here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript)