# Mysql + php datatable not showing particular rows

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I wrote a small python script that takes postfix/dovecot logs and uploads it to mariadb database. The table has only 2 rows, `id(key)` and `log(text)`.

Everything is working except when I search in HTML page for a particular log, it displays this:

```
Oct 30 00:14:26 mailserver postfix/smtpd[1321]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mx.mailbox.rs[109.245.241.198]: 450 4.1.8 : Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=
```

As you see, `"from="`, `"to="`, and `"helo="` are empty and they should be there.

I have a full log in database:

```
Oct 30 00:14:26 mailserver postfix/smtpd[1321]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mx.mailbox.rs[109.245.241.198]: 450 4.1.8 <xxx@xxx.xx>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<xxx@mail.xxx.xxx> to=<xxx@mxxx.xx> proto=ESMTP helo=<mx.mailbox.rs>
```

It seems that `"<>"` these signs are the problem.

Database encoding is `utf8`. I use datatables.net for displaying results and searching the logs.

Here is the code

```
<?php 
// Database connection info 
$dbDetails = array( 
    'host' => 'localhost', 
    'user' => 'xxx', 
    'pass' => 'xxx', 
    'db'   => 'xxx', 
    'charset' => 'utf8'
); 
 
// DB table to use 
$table = 'logs'; 
 
// Table's primary key 
$primaryKey = 'id'; 
 
// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. 
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database.  
// The `dt` parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. 
$columns = array( 
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'log',  'dt' => 1 ), 
); 
 
// Include SQL query processing class 
require 'ssp.class.php'; 
 
// Output data as json format 
echo json_encode( 
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ) 
);
```

```
<!-- DataTables CSS library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables JS library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#memListTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "getData.php"
    });
});
</script>

<table id="memListTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Log</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Log</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>


</html>
```

**EDIT2**

I tried using:

```
function filter(&$value) {
  $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}
array_walk_recursive($columns, "filter");
```

with no luck.

Comment: < and > are html chars, so you need to escape them, you tagged php so presuming your after [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone well, since i use datatables.net i am only displaying data from database.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone how should i do that in this case? Thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: your prob need to use a columnDefs renderer and [then do in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript) due to using that SSP::simple class https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: alternatively instead of directly json_encoding SSP::simple, save to a var and loop over the result with array_map or similar and apply the escaping there

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm dumb for this. Everything i do doesn't work.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i tried 
function filter(&$value) {
  $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}
array_walk_recursive($columns, "filter");

but it doesn't work