# Convert all &, <, > characters to HTML entities

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need the most efficient way to convert all applicable characters to HTML entities.

Two of the solutions I have found on stack overflow are as follow, but one of these involves using DOM and other regular expression.

Using [Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript/784611#784611):

```
return mystring.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

Using [DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript/784698#784698):

```
function HtmlEncode(s)
{
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
  s = el.innerHTML;
  delete el;
  return s;
}
```

Do anyone of you know the efficient solution to convert characters to HTML entities without using any DOM API and regular expression?

Comment: That's like asking how to add numbers without `+`.

Comment: Every character can be converted to an HTML entity; given that you are asking about three characters in particular, I have edited the title of your question. Also, you ask for the "most efficient way" and then rule out two valid ways. Why did you rule out regexp/DOM? Do you not believe that one of them is clearly the mot efficient way?

Comment: Nop, regular expression are bit slow and interacting with DOM API don't seem to be a good idea. Hence I wanted something different. and yes thanks for editing the title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the php.JS lib on the link below.

http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425

Comment: oh! thanks....  "tmp_str = tmp_str.split(symbol).join(entity);" ... I was missing this part...

Answer (score 0):

Coming from the land of "Why on earth would you want to do something like that?"

```
var foo = "Hello, world";
var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    html += "&#" + foo.charCodeAt(i) + ";";
}
alert(html);
```