# Javascript - replace special character code with character

Tags: javascript, replace, special-characters

using javascript, is there a way to replace the special character code's with the special character?
For example:
&amp; becomes &
&copy; becomes ©

Thanks!!

Comment: I've updated my answer, I guess it is what you're looking for!

Comment: Replace in what, the HTML stream or in JavaScript strings?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

The [Encoder.js](http://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js) file from that page seems to do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

See Cerebrus' answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript)

**EDIT**

Actually KooiInc's answer is exactly what are you are looking for

Comment: Is it?  I think the OP is saying "given the entity, replace it with the character."  The linked post is going the other way, from character to entity.  Of course, maybe the OP _meant_ to ask the question Kooilnc answered but it doesn't look that way from the way it was phrased.

Comment: You're right, 3 AM here misunderstood the question. But still, he can always do the other way around. Just build a for statement which goes throug 0 to whatever is the max entity, and then checks whether the entity matches with the html code.