# Escape html & non-ascii chars with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, escaping, non-ascii-characters

OK, so I need to replace all <, & and > plus all non-ascii characters with their html-entity counterparts. I've tried Underscore.string.escapeHTML but that didn't seem to touch the non-ascii chars.

For example I need this:

```
<div>föö bär</div>
```

converted into this:

```
&lt;div&gt;f&ouml;&ouml; b&auml;r&lt;/div&gt;
```

Obviously auml and ouml are not enough. I need a valid ascii string no matter what buttons the users chooses to push, or heaven forbit, even writes with some moonspeak keyboard.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape ?

Comment: Fwiw, I've got underscore + jquery loaded by default, so any hacks with them would be better than loading external libraries.

Comment: 1) that does the url escape thingy. Although I might just be able to work with that, html entities are highly preferred

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499473/need-to-escape-non-ascii-characters-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what you are looking for [here](http://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js)

For the purpose of your needs you have to use **htmlEncode** function.

They define a number of other useful functions within the object:

**HTML2Numerical**: Converts HTML entities to their numerical equivalents.

**NumericalToHTML**: Converts numerical entities to their HTML equivalents.

**numEncode**: Numerically encodes unicode characters.

**htmlDecode**: Decodes HTML encoded text to its original state.

**htmlEncode**: Encodes HTML to either numerical or HTML entities. This is determined by the EncodeType property.

**XSSEncode**: Encodes the basic characters used in XSS attacks to malform HTML.

**correctEncoding**: Corrects any double encoded ampersands.

**stripUnicode**: Removes all unicode characters.

**hasEncoded**: Returns true if a string contains html encoded entities within it.

Source: [www.strictly-software.com](http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode)

Beware of the license agreement - GPL, The MIT License (MIT)

Comment: @user1185421 Probably because it was a link only answer. I fixed that :)