# ognl to javascript data transfer

Tags: javascript, struts2, ognl, data-conversion

I am transferring a string containing quotes from ognl to javascript like this:

```
alert(<s:property value="jsonString"/>);
```

jsonString has value

```
    {"efwef":"wefwef"}
```

the quotes get replaced by `&quot;`

```
{&quot;efwef&quot;:&quot;wefwef&quot;}
```

how do I prevent this?

Comment: Look like the same issue posted here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript

Comment: That is not the same problem.

Comment: <s:property value="jsonString" escape="false"/>

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:property value="jsonString" escape="false"/>
```