# How to convert curly quotes to &#8220;

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert multibyte characters like curly quotes to their equivalent entity like `&#8220;` using jquery or javascript?

```
var userTxt = '“testing”';
```

after converting userTxt should look like => `&#8220;testing&#8221;`

Comment: Shouldn't you use `var userTxt = '“testing”';`

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to do that? If you’re having display problems with characters like this, setting your `Content-Type` HTTP header to `text/html; charset=utf-8` (or an appropriate value if you’re using a different encoding than utf-8) should sort them out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/784765/2220391 works http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/8ftfS/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
$('<div/>').text('This is fun & stuff').html(); // evaluates to "This is fun &amp; stuff"
```

[Source](http://debuggable.com/posts/encode-html-entities-with-jquery:480f4dd6-13cc-4ce9-8071-4710cbdd56cb)

Or you can do it [this way](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

try instead if you can use `$quot` instead of  `&#8220`

```
var e_encoded = e.html().replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
console.log(e_encoded); // outputs &quot;&amp;
```

or you can use this function

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using regular expressions.

```
function replace_quotes( text ){
    return text.replace(/\u201C/g, "&#8220;").replace(/\u201D/g, "&#8221;");
}
```

This function replaces the quote characters by matching their unicode hex code.
See: [Regex Tutorial - Unicode Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint)