# Atmosphere.js package, angular-templates, throws error on less than operator in my binding

Tags: angularjs, meteor, conditional-statements, angular-template, atmosphere.js

The Error being thrown

```
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While processing files with angular-templates (for target web.browser):
   client/templates/rcalendar/day.html:7: Expected tag name after `<`
   ...            {{$index<12?($index === 0?12:...
   ^
   client/templates/rcalendar/week.html:16: Expected tag name after `<`
   ...            {{$index<12?($index === 0?12:...
```

The offending HTML

```
<td class="calendar-cell">
   <div class="add_event_shade" style="height:100%;" ng-if="!tm.events" ng-show"clickCount" on-touch="hourTouch($event)">
      <p style="display:none;">+ New event</p>
      <p style="display:none;">{{$index<12?($index === 0?12:$index)+':00 am':($index === 12?$index:$index-12)+':00 pm'}}</p>
   </div>
   <div ng-class="{'calendar-event-wrap': tm.events}" ng-show="tm.events">
      <div ng-repeat="displayEvent in tm.events" 
             class="calendar-event" 
             ng-click="eventSelected({event:displayEvent.event})"
             ng-style="{left: 100/displayEvent.overlapNumber*displayEvent.position+'%', width: 100/displayEvent.overlapNumber+'%', top: displayEvent.event.startTimeOffset+'%', height: 37*(displayEvent.event.totalApptTime)+'px'}">
          <div class="calendar-event-inner" style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-weight: bold">{{displayEvent.event.title}}</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

How can I set conditionals in my bindings like this?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264586/escaping-characters-in-ng-bind-in-angularjs

Comment: unrelated, but shouldn't you put that inside a filter instead of directly in the template? Not very readable like this...

Comment: @Pevara probably cleaner. It's a lib that I installed in my ionic application. It wasn't throwing errors until I tried to move the ionic application inside the client directory of a Meteor app to use for my backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do something like this :

```
<p style="display:none;">
    {{($index < 12 && $index === 0)? 12 : $index}}:00 am
    {{$index === 12? $index : ($index - 12)}}:00 pm
</p>
```

But be careful, you put a `display:none` in the `p` tag.

---

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, to avoid the error given by `angular-template` we can call a function from the controller instead of evaluating the expression in the `p` tag

```
<p>{{getTime($index)}}</p>
```

Comment: The problem isn't how it's displaying. [angular-templates](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/angular-templates) thinks the less than symbol is an opening HTML tag bracket without a closing one. I already tried adding space between `$index` the less than symbol and `12`. It throws the same error.

Comment: Alright I see the problem now. Instead of evaluating an expression in the `p` tag, you could call a function from your controller like this : `<p style="display:none;">{{getTime($index)}}</p>` ? (And you can do the logic in the `getTime()` function)

Comment: Thanks @JeanMel. I had considered that. As I just mentioned to @Pevara above, I was just wondering if there was a way to format the less than symbol so that `angular-templates` wouldn't think it was a opening HTML bracket. If that isn't possible then moving it to the controller is probably the route I will go.