# PHP variable (with quotes) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to access a PHP variable in JavaScript. I've escaped quotes in the PHP variable and the JavaScript won't pick it up. Without changing the $a1 php variable, how can I access it in JavaScript?

```
<?php

$a1 = "Here is the \"best\" apple around";    //<-- doesn't work in javascript...
$a2 = "Here is the best apple around";        //<--works fine in javascript...

?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str = "<?php echo $a1; ?>";
alert(str);

</script>
```

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628262/how-to-display-double-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: `<?php echo addslashes($a1);?>`

Comment: Well, the easiest way would be to use `'` in both the PHP and the Javascript, e.g., http://codepad.org/SI71916p

Comment: I recommend using json_encode for simplicity and consistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for *simplicity and consistency*. See [the ideone example](http://ideone.com/o6r2cZ).

```php
<?php
    $a1 = "Here is the \"best\" apple around"; 
?>
var str = <?php echo json_encode($a1); ?>;
```

Result:

```javascript
var str = "Here is the \"best\" apple around";
```

Don't supply quotes in the JavaScript itself, as those come from the encoded result as required.

Advantages:

- Correct. The result always represents a valid JavaScript literal (or object/array) expression.
- Simple. No need to worry about quotes in JavaScript when dealing with string values.
- Consistent. The same approach works for many values - e.g. arrays (indexed, keyed, and complex), numbers, booleans, NULL - and preserves more type information.
- Secure. Using `json_encode` [prevents script-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210367/2864740), with the default options.

Comment: You say the output of `json_encode` is invalid, is that because it is a string rather than an object or an array? They changed that in the [latest version of the JSON spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) so that a json text can be any json value (surrounded by any amount of whitespace).

Comment: It's just so that parsers don't fall over when you have a new line at the end of the file / indentation / etc.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks again for the update - and yes, the original aside was because I was not aware of spec changes. It's nice to see that that JSON now encompasses primitive values at the top-level.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on where you want to output your "str" ( in an alert or on a html page ) i would take different commands.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str = "<?php echo addslashes($a1); ?>";
alert(str);

</script>
```

If you would like to add it as a new DOM element i would prefer `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` .

As an alternative:

`var str = <?php echo json_encode($a1, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>;`

Answer (score -2):

use htmlspecialchars to convert $a1

```
$a1 = htmlspecialchars("Here is the \"best\" apple around");
```

Comment: Not appropriate for use within a SCRIPT element.