# How do I show single and double quotes in a text alert in javascript?

Tags: javascript, alert, quotes, double-quotes

I want a javascript alert that reads, "It's "Hammer" time!"

What is the best code to write this?

Comment: A simple googling would solve your problem. Why waste a question on this?

Comment: What have you tried? Some basic research on "javascript alerts" and "escaping characters" would have explained how to do this.

Comment: or alternatively `alert('"It\'s "Hammer" time!"');`, or use template literals. But seriously, you could have researched this in less time than it took to write the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you could use a string with `'` and escape the `'`, or a string with `"` and escape the `"`s, it would be better to use a template literal, which doesn't require escaping of quotes because its delimiter is the backtick:

```js
alert(`"It's "Hammer" time!"`);
```

Answer (score 1):

For displaying single or double quotes, you can write your code like this `alert("\"It's \"Hammer\" time!\"")`

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `"s` other than the ones from the begining and ending..

```js
alert("\"It's \"Hammer\" time!\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it using `\`

For example:

```
alert("Something \"here\"!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to display double quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628262/how-to-display-double-quotes-in-javascript)

Or use string interpolation, where you can have both without escaping.

```js
alert(`Hello, I'm "nobody"!`);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it cause I answered a bad question and support lazy people? Or cause I called it "string interpolation", and not "template literal"?