# How do I add an inches (") symbol to a POST mathematical equation answer using Node JS/Express?

Tags: node.js

### What I'm Doing

I am building a [picture frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_frame) calculator using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) with [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) & [EJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs).

### Code

```
app.post("/measurements/calculate", (req,res) => {
    
    let FrameWidth = req.body.FrameWidth;
    let FrameWidthFraction = req.body.FrameWidthFraction
    let FrameHeight = req.body.FrameHeight;
    let FrameHeightFraction = req.body.FrameHeightFraction;
    let PictureWidth = req.body.PictureWidth;
    let PictureWidthFraction = req.body.PictureWidthFraction;
    let PictureHeight = req.body.PictureHeight;
    let PictureHeightFraction = req.body.PictureHeightFraction;
    let MatOverlap = req.body.MatOverlap;
    let width = (1/2)*((FrameHeight+FrameHeightFraction)-(PictureHeight+PictureHeightFraction)+MatOverlap);
    let height = (1/2)*((FrameWidth+FrameWidthFraction)-(PictureWidth+PictureWidthFraction)+MatOverlap);
    res.send(`Width = ${new Fraction(height).toString()}, Height = ${new Fraction(width).toString()}`);
});
```

Then when I do a JSON POST query via [Postman](https://www.postman.com/product/api-client/) with say:

```
{
    "FrameWidth": 16,
    "FrameWidthFraction": 0,
    "FrameHeight": 20,
    "FrameHeightFraction": 0,
    "PictureWidth": 11,
    "PictureWidthFraction": 0,
    "PictureHeight": 17,
    "PictureHeightFraction": 0,
    "MatOverlap": 0.5
}
```

Then the resulting correct answer/response is:  `Width = 2 3/4, Height = 1 3/4`

### The Problem

I am having trouble including the inches symbol `"` with the answer.  In other words,  I'm trying to get the answer from:

`Width = 2 3/4, Height = 1 3/4`

To

`Width = 2 3/4", Height = 1 3/4"`

I've attempted to interact with this line by adding `"` in different ways with no luck:

```
res.send(`Width = ${new Fraction(height).toString()"}, Height = ${new Fraction(width).toString()"}`);
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20628314/7628937

Comment: Could you please post on what are you receiving? when are you adding like this?
`res.send(\`Width = ${new Fraction(height).toString()}'', Height = ${new Fraction(width).toString()}''\`);`

Comment: @sina.ce - That was the answer!  I have no idea how I overlooked that.  When I added your line, then the response was: `Width = 2 3/4' ', Height = 1 3/4' '`.  So, I needed to tweak it with inches:  `res.send(`Width = ${new Fraction(height).toString()}", Height = ${new Fraction(width).toString()}"`);`.  And it worked:  `Width = 2 3/4", Height = 1 3/4"`  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Much obliged :), could you please accept my answer?

Comment: There isn't any `"` in your "attempt". A quick read of the documentation about [JavaScript template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) will help you understand the meaning of the symbols in your expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please  try this:

```
res.send(`Width = ${new Fraction(height).toString()}'', Height = ${new Fraction(width).toString()}''`);
```