# Convert php's htmlspecialchars() with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable written from PHP into my javascript (using `json_encode`), that looks a little like this:

```
mappoints[x]['about'] = 'Administrator: Foo Barlt;br /&gt;Telephone: 555-4202&lt;br /&gt;Email: bert@hotmail.com&lt;br /&gt;Website: www.domain.com'
```

That I am using for a google maps map point.  Using the `json_encode` seems to be very picky about what characters I can and cannot enter into it, so i am wondering how I can convert those special html characters into real html characters using javascript?

**update**

The way i am building my variable is:

```
var description = "<h3 style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>" + mappoints[x]['name'] + "</h3><b>Director:</b> " + mappoints[x]['director'] + "<br/>" + mappoints[x]['about'];
```

The HTML in the varaible is all fine, until I add the `about` index.  No function I have attached or tried yet seems to give me proper HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the dom to decode those entities for you.

```
mappoints[x]['about'] = 'Administrator: Foo Barlt;br /&gt;Telephone: 555-4202&lt;br /&gt;Email: bert@hotmail.com&lt;br /&gt;Website: www.domain.com'
mappoints[x]['about'] = $('<div/>').append(mappoints[x]['about']).text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5FTCX/

Basically when you add the html to the dom it will show the entities as the characters they represent, using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) you can receive the data back as you'd see it in the browser as `text`, not html with the entities. If you want back the html you can use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) [e.g.](http://jsfiddle.net/5FTCX/3/).

Comment: If you append to DOM, the chars are interpreted as HTML, so when you use text() you get the string already interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be okay with :

```
return mystring.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

From here : [Convert special characters to HTML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just because @Musa's idea was great but needed some re-interpreting on my side, I wish to post a quick function here, that will handle htmlspecialchars great, based on @Musa's design :

`function htmlspecialchars_decode(string) {
    $('body').append("<span style='display:none;visibility:hidden;' id='tempText'>" + string + "</span>");
    var result = $('#tempText').text();
    $('#tempText').remove();
    return result;
};`

Comment: And it leaves no trace.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
decodeURIComponent(str) or `unescape(str)` or `decodeURI(str)`
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work :(