# How to escape html entities within a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish to escape the contents of the user entered value, so they show up as html entities.  i.e. < would show up in the HTML markup as `&lt;`.  But I want to wrap the user entered value with actual html.  The idea is that I should be able to escape the user entered value, yet still trust the html.

Here is my html snippet:
`<span ng-bind-html="trustHtml(notif.getConditionText())"></span>`

Controller:

```
$scope.trustHtml = function(html) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
}
```

Notif:

```
getConditionText: function() {
    return "<b>" + $sanitize(this.name) + "</b>";
}
```

I'm looking for a function that would go in place of $sanitize that would escape the user entered "name" property value. i.e. if they entered `Seattle <rocks>` it would output the html as `Seattle &lt;rocks&gt;`

Anyone know of something like this for angular?

Note I am not trying to encode to URI entities, but HTML entities.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: So you just want to [escape HTML special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode html entities in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, but I am hoping for an "angular best practice" way of doing it.  It seems like there should be something out there, what with the $sce and $sanitize providers

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this: [Convert special characters to HTML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript)

where u can write a function like:

```
function HtmlEncode(s)
{
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
  s = el.innerHTML;
  return s;
}
```

and get it encoded. Now, I didn't found something specific to angularjs.

I hope it helps

Comment: I'm hesitant to use this due to potential XSS attacks injecting into the DOM... can anyone comment on its secure usage?