# How to extract the array from the string which is a JSON response

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting the following response from the JSON which is in the string format and inside there is an array.

`"[&quot;Password first character can not be blank&quot;, &quot;Current password can&#39;t be blank&quot;]"`

I tried to extract the my required array object by using the following method.

```
errorMessages = "[&quot;Password first character can not be blank&quot;, &quot;Current password can&#39;t be blank&quot;]"
jQuery.parseJSON( errorMessages )
```

But it is not working for me, can anybody please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you try this `JSON.parse(errorMessages.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));`

Comment: @erkaner,  Ohh.. !Thank you so much. But this is only the way or any direct method available in jQuery? Can you suggest of you know any?

Comment: the actual data is coming from a ruby object right. Can you try for obj.html_safe or JSON.parse(obj) on ruby object itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `JSON.stringify` to get your json object? `JSON.stringify` may prevent `&quot;`

IF you still have the problem, you may just replace the `&quot;` with `"`

```
JSON.parse(errorMessages.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
```

Comment: That should work, but that is a hard approach. If OP is passing such a string, then all special characters will have this format. Parse all of them?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can pass the data in a way that JS can convert to JSON, you have to use this:

> The best way in my opinion is to use the browser's inbuilt HTML escape
>   functionality to handle many of the cases. To do this simply create a
>   element in the DOM tree and set the innerText of the element to your
>   string. Then retrieve the innerHTML of the element. The browser will
>   return an HTML encoded string.
>
> ```
> function HtmlEncode(s)
> {
>   var el = document.createElement("div");
>   el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
>   s = el.innerHTML;
>   return s;
> }
> ```
>
> Test run:
>
> ```
> alert(HtmlEncode('&;\'><"'));
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> &amp;;'&gt;&lt;"
> ```
>
> This method of escaping HTML is also used by the Prototype JS library
>   though differently from the simplistic sample I have given.
>
> Note: You will still need to escape quotes (double and single)
>   yourself. You can use any of the methods outlined by others here.

Quoted from: [Cerebrus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you are getting working with an output of **`htmlspecialchars()`**. You can use this simple function to first decode it and parse it as an array. Therefore, the whole function will be like.

```
var errorMessages = '[&quot;Password first character can not be blank&quot;, &quot;Current password can&#39;t be blank&quot;]';

function decodehtml(text) {
  return text
      .replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
      .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
      .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
      .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
      .replace(/&#39;|&#039;/g, "'");
}

var errorArray = JSON.parse(decodehtml(errorMessages));
```