# Converting special character entity name into actual symbols

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, entity, symbols

i am getting a json in return whose value is &<>" and many more special character.I want a common solution to convert all of them into their actual values like &amp as &,&quot into ",,etc.
I dont want to use anthing like the below code because in future more different symbols can come-

```
    $scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext=$scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
    $scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext=$scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext.replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
    $scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext=$scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
    $scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext=$scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
    $scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext=$scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext.replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
```

Is there any api to handle these value and convert them into their actual value?
I am using angularJs.

Comment: So, you need to parse HTML?

Comment: i want to parse the data which i am gettiingg from JSON and then display them in a HTML page.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/784698/1430607

Comment: here quotes (double and single) are not handled...i need to be total accurate...

Comment: I updated the example for clearness

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using angular, you can use jQuery.

Just create an element with jQuery, and then parse it using its text() property

```
var str = $( "<span>&quotDale ca&ntilde;a&quot&#169;</span>" ).text();
console.log(str);
```

The output is "Dale caña"©

You will need to put your string within a valid html tag, such as `'<span>'+yourtext+'</span>'`

### **[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smegggy8/)**

*click on "run" and open your browser's console*

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer...working for all the characters(which i checked)...

```
$scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext=$('<textarea />').html($scope.oldNotification[i].shorttext).text();
```