# Javascript can't change text after typing some text on textarea

Tags: javascript, html

After typing some text on the `textarea` these three button is to working.

> I inspect that in google chrome and I saw in html rendered code it successfully adds `innerHtml` but it doesn't show it on `textarea`.

**Why it is not working?**

**How can I solve this problem?**

```js
    function clickTicK(element){
        var texta = document.getElementById(element);
        texta.innerHTML = '&#x2714;';
    }
    function clickCross(element){
        var texta = document.getElementById(element);
        texta.innerHTML = '&#x2718;';
    }

    function enable(element) {
        var texta = document.getElementById(element);
        texta.innerHTML = '';
    }
```

```html
<textarea name="textareaname" id="textareaid" placeholder="click here to edit"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="enable('textareaid');">&#9998;</button><br>
<button onclick="clickTicK('textareaid');">&#x2714;</button><br>
<button onclick="clickCross('textareaid');">&#x2718;</button>
```

If I use `textarea.value` then it works but shows code "&#x2714" or "&#x2718" but not symbol.

```js
        function clickTicK(element){
            var texta = document.getElementById(element);
            texta.value = '&#x2714;';
        }
        function clickCross(element){
            var texta = document.getElementById(element);
            texta.value = '&#x2718;';
        }

        function enable(element) {
            var texta = document.getElementById(element);
            texta.value = '';
        }
```

```html
    <textarea name="textareaname" id="textareaid" placeholder="click here to edit"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="enable('textareaid');">&#9998;</button><br>
    <button onclick="clickTicK('textareaid');">&#x2714;</button><br>
    <button onclick="clickCross('textareaid');">&#x2718;</button>
```

Comment: textarea does not have innerHTML, it as a value like all other inputs.

Comment: But it works, when i don't type any text on textarea

Comment: Your example works for me.

Comment: As said, You should use value and not innerHTML. You can convert the special characters in javascript. Checkout the most voted answer from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript

Comment: This is not what i meant in my question @AcidBurn

Comment: To convert "&#x2714" or "&#x2718" to the symbols, you can use any of the methods from that stackoverflow link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to extract the html you want and then set the value to that. See example below:

```js
function clickTicK(element){
        var texta = document.getElementById(element);
        texta.value = $('<span>').html('&#x2714;').html();
    }
    function clickCross(element){
        var texta = document.getElementById(element);
        texta.value = $('<span>').html('&#x2718;').html();
    }

    function enable(element) {
        var texta = document.getElementById(element);
        texta.value = '';
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea name="textareaname" id="textareaid" placeholder="click here to edit"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="enable('textareaid');">&#9998;</button><br>
<button onclick="clickTicK('textareaid');">&#x2714;</button><br>
<button onclick="clickCross('textareaid');">&#x2718;</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `value` not `innerHTML` on `<textarea/>`

```js
function clickTicK(element){
        var texta = document.getElementById(element);
        texta.value = '&#x2714;';
    }
    function clickCross(element){
        var texta = document.getElementById(element);
        texta.value = '&#x2718;';
    }

    function enable(element) {
        var texta = document.getElementById(element);
        texta.value = '';
    }
```

```html
<textarea name="textareaname" id="textareaid" placeholder="click here to edit"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="enable('textareaid');">&#9998;</button><br>
<button onclick="clickTicK('textareaid');">&#x2714;</button><br>
<button onclick="clickCross('textareaid');">&#x2718;</button>
```

Comment: but it dont show the symbol ... it shows the code "&#x2718;" or "&#x2714;"

Comment: Try `texta.value = $('<div>').html('&#x2714;').html();`