# jQuery or vanilla JavaScript: Replace or escape all < and >

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like this

```
<div id="asdf">
  <div>
    <p>ASDF IS AWESOME</p>
  </div>
  <h1>Just another Headline</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="listitem">Hey</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and need a `jQuery` or `vanilla JavaScript` function, method to convert the whole stuff into this

```
&lt;div id="asdf"
  &lt;div&gt;
    &lt;p>ASDF IS AWESOME&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;h1>Just another Headline&lt;/h1&gt;
  &lt;nav&gt;
    &lt;ul&gt;
      &lt;li class="listitem"Hey&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;/ul&gt;
  &lt;/nav&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

so I just want to escape the `<` and `>`

I tried `.replace` and `.text()`

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript

Comment: You can check my answer below using only one function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that

```js
var html = $('#asdf').html();
var escaped=$('<div/>').text(html).html();
console.log(escaped);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="asdf">
  <div>
    <p>ASDF IS AWESOME</p>
  </div>
  <h1>Just another Headline</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="listitem">Hey</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#asdf").prop("outerHTML")` would be a better idea - since `#asdf` should be also included

Answer (score 0):

Try this: *Using only 1 function, then you can use it wherever you want*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $selector = $('#asdf');      
  console.log(htmlEntities($selector));
  function htmlEntities(str) {
    str = str.html();
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="asdf">
  <div>
    <p>ASDF IS AWESOME</p>
  </div>
  <h1>Just another Headline</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="listitem">Hey</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

You can reference this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/