# Get the name of HTML-Special-Characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to get the name of HTML-Special-Characters programmatically in JavaScript?
Per example [something like here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript)

```
function HtmlEncode(s)
{
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
  s = el.innerHTML;
  return s;
}

Test run:
alert(HtmlEncode('&;\'><"'));

Output:
&amp;;'&gt;&lt;"
```

But the function of @Cerebrus (see link above) doesn't work always.
`alert(HtmlEncode('$§©'));`

Per example it fails for following characters:

```
$ : &dollar;
& : &amp;
§ : &sect;
© : &copy;
...
```

Any idea, how can I get the name of HTML Special Characters?
(I mean programmatically like above, but no list-name like a map).
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a map, no matter if you compile it yourself or use [someone else's](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he/blob/master/data/entities.json).

Comment: Someone left a comment (now removed) with a good point about the use case. It'd be interesting to know why exactly you need this feature for (it isn't obvious at all)—that can help to get alternative solutions you might not have considered.

Comment: I'm trying to create a javascript tool, which will be able to show all html special characters. It would be nice, if the tool would show the name of the characters too. A map will be to large! So I'm looking for a small solution, otherwise I'll give it up :).