# Don't know how to render html which is given as a string from get request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I make a get request and receive data. There is a property like:

```
<pre class="some-class" spellcheck="false">&lt;p&gt;SomeText&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;div class="article__image"&gt;
&nbsp;&lt;img alt="alt-text" src="null" data-src="/upload/images/11.jpg" class="img--responsive lazyload"&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</pre><p>&nbsp;&lt;br&gt;</p>
```

I render it like that:

```
<template>
  <div class="screen card">
    <div><pre v-html="text"></pre></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

- I tried to render it with `v-html`, but it just rendered the text above.
- I tried `<div>{{ data }}</div>` and the effect was the same.
- I tried to put `v-html` into `<pre></pre>` and pre tag wasn't rendered as plain text, and divs, img, p were.
  It renders like that:
  [image]
  The rest of props renders fine, but no this one. Can somebody help me?

Comment: So do I understand this correctly, you want to render the text so it looks like html on the page without it being interpreted as html?

Comment: @ioasjfopas I want to render data as html, but it renders it as a plain string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render your data as HTML, you need to remove the [HTML Escape Characters](https://mateam.net/html-escape-characters/) (`&lt;`, `&gt`, etc.), as they will be rendered as `<` and `>`.

Your HTML should then be valid.
This here worked for me:

```js
<template>
  <div class="screen card">
    <div>
      <div v-html="text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      text: `
      <pre 
        class="some-class" spellcheck="false">
        SomeText
        
        <div class="article__image">
          <img alt="alt-text" src="null" data-src="/upload/images/11.jpg" class="img--responsive lazyload">
        </div>
      </pre>
      <p><br></p>
      `,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Result:

[image: The text rendered as html]

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get rid of it because I get it from backend

Comment: @thirtythreeboas Then you need to replace the escape codes you get with the actual characters (`&lt;` to `<`, etc.). Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript